# Jquery multiple file upload without choose file

Tags: javascript, jquery

In am looking for JQuery script that will allow me to put multiple audio file to my server without choose file option.

I have three audio file on some path. Now I need to upload this three audio file to my server with different parameters like audio1, audio2, audio3 in single submit button using JQuery script.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is You **can't**

You can only make the user click the input button and then make him choose the files.

Even if you find a workaround for doing it from code(*Which is quite impossible for me*),

The browsers will never allow you to bypass their security measures.

Even if it is supported today, most browsers are intelligent and learning day by day.

They sure will unsupport it in the very near future

So there's no chance of achieving what you want.

## Why ?

Let's assume that you have some personal photos in some folders. If the browsers allow the files to be uploaded, then any one can have access to your **personal** files, which are meant to be personal.So browsers will not allow that. This is the reason why you can't do what you are trying to do.

Comment: It possible to send audio file to my server using jquery without choose file option instead of that i mentioned file path?

Comment: no mate, you need to place a file control like `<input type="file">` and then only user can select the files and send it. Jquery is just a library to make it easy for javascripters